# Catching a KeyboardInterrupt and resuming after a pause has occured

Tags: python, python-2.7, pause

I'm trying to catch a keyboard interrupt and resume after the user chooses to resume the process using the following code:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    q = prompt("CNTRL-C was pressed what would you like to do", "quit(q)/pause(p)")
    if q.lower().startswith("q"):
        shutdown(0)
    elif q.lower().startswith("p"):
        LOGGER.warning("Application will pause until a key is pressed..")
        try:
            os.system("pause")
        except:
            os.system("read -p")
    else:
        shutdown(0) # shut down is just exit with a log message
```

However it seems that everytime I attempt to do this after I press the key to continue, it just exits the process:

```
[*] Starting up at: 1498843527.18..

[12:25:27 INFO] Using algorithm, MSSQL 2000..
[12:25:27 PROMPT] CNTRL-C was pressed what would you like to do[quit(q)/pause(p)]: p
[12:25:28 WARNING] Application will pause until a key is pressed..
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I get the program to remember what I was doing and then resume the same process after the user has decided to?

Comment: To answer this, we would have to see more of the program. What you are showing, after the pause, it should exit since there is nothing else in the script.

Comment: @RobertB What about caching, would that be possible?

Comment: Suppose instead of `os.system("pause")`, you were just printing 5: `print 5`. How would you resume after printing 5? Do that. (Also, `os.system("pause")` is a bad way to pause a Python script.)

Comment: @user2357112 can you clarify what you just said?